# Terminate threads in a thread pool for Multiple Tenant

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, thread-safety, threadpool

I'm creating a Threadpool as shown below for a job.

```
public class MoveToCherwellThreadPool {

public static ThreadPoolExecutor cherwellMoveThreadPoolExecutor = null;
private static EMLogger logger = EMLogger.getLogger();
private static final String CLASSNAME = "MoveToCherwellThreadPool";

    public static void initiateCherwellMoveThreadPool() {
        BlockingQueue<Runnable> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100000);
        cherwellMoveThreadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10,20, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS, q);
        cherwellMoveThreadPoolExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r,
                    ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
                logger.logDebug(CLASSNAME,"Rejected task cherwellMoveThreadPoolExecutor Active tasks : " + cherwellMoveThreadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount() + ", " + "cherwellMoveThreadPoolExecutor Completed tasks : " + cherwellMoveThreadPoolExecutor.getCompletedTaskCount()+" Waiting for a second !! ");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                executor.execute(r);
            }
        });
    }
    
}
```

I'm using this during a process running for multiple customers. For each customer new threadpool will be initialized and threads will be running.
Below is the code where I'm using the threadpool.

```
for (Object[] objects : relationshipList) {
                        CherwellRelationshipMoveThread relationshipThread = new CherwellRelationshipMoveThread(objects,
                                this.customerId, sb, credential,mainCIId,moveUniqueId,this.startTime);
                        CompletableFuture<?> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(relationshipThread,
                                MoveToCherwellThreadPool.cherwellMoveThreadPoolExecutor);
                        crelationshipList.add(future);
                }
                crelationshipList.forEach(CompletableFuture::join);
```

This thread will be created for multiple customers. I'm giving an option to terminate this job in UI. On click of stop process I need to stop/kill only the threads running for that particular customer and other customer's thread shouldn't be harmed and should be keep running.

On click of stop process from UI I'm calling a service where inside the service my code will be

```
MoveToCherwellThreadPool.cherwellMoveThreadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow();
```

I'm calling shutdownNow() on the ThreadPoolExecutor.

This is killing all the threads of all the customers. I don't want to kill all the customers process, but only for the customer where I'll click on stop process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code doesn't maintain any mapping from a tenant to a thread pool, there's only one static reference to a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Each time `initiateCherwellMoveThreadPool` is called, any existing executor will be replaced with a new one, and the existing one isn't shut down, so it will leak resources. As a result, this will execute tasks from multiple tenants in the same thread pool.

This code is also not thread safe. It's possible (if unlikely) that a thread could schedule a task on a newly-created executor, or even shut it down, before `setRejectedExecutionHandler` is called.

If you need a separate executor per tenant, this will need to be implemented. A good option might be to use a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) with `customerId` keys and `ThreadPoolExecutor` values, for example (logging omitted for brevity):

```java
public class MoveToCherwellThreadPool {
    public static ConcurrentMap<String, ThreadPoolExecutor> cherwellMoveThreadPoolExecutors = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public static ThreadPoolExecutor getCherwellMoveThreadPool(String customerId) {
        return cherwellMoveThreadPoolExecutors.computeIfAbsent(customerId, id -> {
            BlockingQueue<Runnable> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100000);
            ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 20, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS, q);
            executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() { /*...*/ });
            return executor;
        });
    }

    public static List<Runnable> stopCherwellMoveTheadPool(String customerId) {
        if (cherwellMoveThreadPoolExecutors.containsKey(customerId)) {
            return cherwellMoveThreadPoolExecutors.get(customerId).shutdownNow();
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

}
```

This can be used like this:

```
CompletableFuture<?> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(relationshipThread,
    MoveToCherwellThreadPool.getCherwellMoveThreadPool(customerId));
```

It's also important to realise that calling [`shutdownNow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdownNow--) can only *attempt* to cancel currently executing tasks, and "does not wait for actively executing tasks to terminate":

> This implementation cancels tasks via [`Thread.interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--), so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.

The code implementing `CherwellRelationshipMoveThread` isn't shown, so this may or may not be the case.

Comment: Hello Tim, 
If you need a separate executor per tenant, this will need to be implemented. A good option might be to use a ConcurrentHashMap with customerId keys and ThreadPoolExecutor values.


Can you give me an example on this one?

Comment: If I create a separate thread pool for each tenant, can I shutdown that threadpool so that the threads wont go to the wait/park state for a long time till it gets a new tasks.

Comment: Also I was trying to initialize the thread pool when my tomcat server is started, but since I want to create each thread pool to each tenant I want to initialize the thread pool when I'm triggering my scheduled task.

Comment: Does the task use multiple threads internally? If the task is itself single threaded, and you want the thread to start when the task runs and stop when it finishes, you might not need a thread pool at all, but just an ordinary thread.

Comment: I have multiple threads running internally.

Comment: @Sanjay I added some example code. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: This is working perfectly fine for me. Thank you Tim.